# Inherit form view from a predefined module

Tags: odoo, inheritance

I want to create my own module which is an extension of `sale.order`. I want to have a form view which is like `sale order` view with few additional fields, 
My problem is that when I inherit the `sale order` view and add say three extra fields these fields comes by default in the Original `Sale Order` form view too.

is this the default behaviour or am I doing something wrong ?
What should I do to achieve what I want.

Comment: Hello Nagri, Please provide some code so that it will help in detecting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inherit the view and add some fields using 'xpath' , than it will change the original view by installing your new module. This is the application of view inheritance. If you want to keep the original form view as it is after the installation of your module and want to define another which have some extra fields only for your customized module, you have to make a different form view without inheriting the original one. May be in future , there will be a facility of extending an existing form view, but right now you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check view_id in your code may be a view_id is common so you are updating a default view of sale order.

When you are inherit one view of sale order a functionality will be added in a form not whole view will be generated.

Still this is not solution send me your code i will review it.