# Inherit views while preserving the original view

Tags: inheritance, view, odoo

For Openerp or alternatively Odoo I would like to develop a module, in particular we would like to extend a view while preserving the original view, similar as questioned in "[Inherit form view from a predefined module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770690/inherit-form-view-from-a-predefined-module)". From the voted answer I gather that this sort of behavior is not supported by design at the time.

In the reference documentation of [Odoo Views](http://odoo-80.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/views.html) I noticed the field 'inheritance mode'. Which seems to suggest that in the event of an inherited view, the view can still be explicitly marked as primary (to my understanding a sort of top level view?). If my understanding is correct, then in accordance of section 'View resolution' in the documentation, views marked primary, should not have an effect on the form where they inherit from but instead be able to be served side by side.

It would be greatly appreciated if anybody more versed in the Odoo-verse could confirm if this is the intend around this 'inheritance mode' or if it serves for an entire different concept. Is *"extending"* a view still unsupported in the newest version?

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct. When the view `mode` is `primary`, the original view remains untouched.

You can use this to make alternative views for the same (or even different) model.